Serlialisation algorithm for trees
I am working on a problem to serlialise a n-ary tree.
I see most solutions on leetcode use DFS traversal to visit all the child nodes till null is reached and then place a marker.
In this specific problem, I am creating the tree level wise i.e child nodes are assigned randomly to the parent nodes of the previous level.And all nodes will not have n childs.
So I think it would be better to use BFS for serealisation for each level.
I want to understand the pros and cons of using DFS based serealisation vs BFS based.
Is there a scenario when BFS is better in terms of space complexity ?

It's unclear what you mean by "child nodes are assigned randomly to the parent nodes of the previous level." Are you asking how to serialize a complete n-ary tree? Or an n-ary tree that is not completely filled (i.e. not every node has n children)?

(Good thinking if you came up with the final question on your own.)
